# how to add middleware in nodejs controller?

Tags: node.js

I have a router.js like below:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const signupController = require('../controller/signup.controller');
const signinController = require('../controller/signin.controller');
const userListController = require('../controller/userList.controller');
const productController = require('../controller/product.controller');

const passport = require('passport');
require('../config/passport')(passport);


router.get('/users', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), userListController.getUserList);

router.post('/product', productController.addProduct)

router.post('/user/signup', signupController.Signup);

router.post('/user/signin', signinController.Signin);


module.exports = router;
```

and in productController.addProduct I have this code:

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Product = require('../model/product.model');
var multer = require('multer');
var path = require('path');


// File storage configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, '...store some where in filesystem...');
    }
});

// File filter configuration
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if (path.extname(file) === '.gpg') {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};

// File upload configuration
const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
    },
    //fileFilter: fileFilter
});


// Loader module
exports.addProduct = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    ...    
}
```

how I can add upload into exports.addProduct = (req, res, next) => {}, so I can access req.file

I have tried it something like this, but didn't work :

exports.addProduct = (upload.single('productImage'),(req, res, next) => {}

Comment: try something along those lines https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node/issues/278

Answer (score 2):

I would try this:

In `productController` also export your `upload`. So you need to add:

```
exports.upload = upload;

// Loader module
exports.addProduct = ... // like in your code
```

As the Router-function expects all callbacks, modify your `router.js` like this :

```
router.post('/product', productController.upload, productController.addProduct);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your `router.js`, add

```
router.post('/product',productController.upload, productController.addProduct);
```

In `productController.js`:

```
module.exports.upload=(upload.single('image')), (request, response, next)=>{
    next();
}
```

In `productController.js`

```
module.exports.addProduct=(  (request,response, next)=>{
 console.log(request.file);
next();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When you give answers, try to explain what the code does and not just present it. Be as detailed as possible.